# Load store view from a blank page

Tags: php, redirect, store-view, ce-1.9.1.0, htaccess

I created 2 blank page that have these address (Note that are different domains):

- www.mysite.com/cars.phtml (store_view_code = en)
- www.mysite.it/auto.phtml (store_view_code = it)

From cars.pthml page I would switching to auto.phtml page.

I tried to do this:

```
    $params = array(
       '_current' => TRUE,
       '_use_rewrite' => TRUE,
       '_store_to_url' => TRUE,
       '_store' => it
       );
    $url = Mage::getUrl('', $params);
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
```

But redirection works partially because it redirect from 'www.mysite.com/cars.phtml' to 'www.mysite.it/cars.phtml' and generated obviously a 404 error.

To completeness this is how I set my .htaccess to handle store view redirection:

```
    #######################################################
    SetEnvIf Host www\.mysite\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=en
    SetEnvIf Host ^mysite\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=en

    SetEnvIf Host www\.mysite\.it MAGE_RUN_CODE=it
    SetEnvIf Host ^mysite\.it MAGE_RUN_CODE=it
```

Comment: Did you tried the built in Magento tool for this? It is under Catalog - Url rewrite

Comment: Right suggestion. I thought there was already a url rewrite for that address. Thank you.

Comment: I added this as an answer. Please mark it as accepted if this issue is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the URL rewrite feature under Catalog - RL rewrite to solve this.